# Why does this MySQL database have 6 backup copies on different mounted drives on the same server

Tags: mysql, database-replication, database-backups

I am new to managing a database. I have taken over a MySQL database on Azure. I decided to make sure everything was backed up properly. I am confused by what I found. This MySQL database is on an ubuntu server with 6 drives. The drives are :

```
A. sda1: Premium SSD (old Copy of DB) 30G 
B. sdb1: Standard HDD (Up do Date) 60G 
C. sdc1: Standard SSD (Old Copy) 1T 
D. sdd1: Standard SSD (Old Copy) 1T 
E. sde1: Standard SSD (Old Copy) 4T 
F. sdf1: Standard SSD (Old Copy) 4T
```

I first thought they were using replication with 2. being the master. But there has been no update and I cannot find any .cnf file setting up the slaves. I have these following questions.

1. What scheme are they using?
2. Why would they have so many copies on the same server on different drives?
3. Should I set up replication on these drives if they are on the same server?
4. How can I bring all the (old copy) drives up to date?

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that there were no automatic backups on the server.

1. There was no backup schema
2. They didn't have a reason. They just weren't comfortable setting up azure databases and setup something they didn't understand.
3. Replication can be setup as normal.
4. Standard backup procedures were used.